# Nikon ViewNX-i and sidecar files

Tags: nikon, raw, software, sidecar

I wanted to use Nikon View NX-i to set the GPS coordinates in my raw files but it seems the data are always going to a sidecar file.

I got a folder NKSC_PARAM aside of my raws with .nksc files inside that seems to contain the GPS coordinates.

I wanted that Nikon ViewNX-i store the GPS coordinates in the RAWs and not in sidecar files.

I checked all the settings and did not find any setting I can change for that.

Do you know if it's possible to force Nikon View NX-i not to use sidecar files?

Comment: Hello @puffp, did you ever got an answer for your question? I am in the same trouble as you. I'd like to modify my .JPG file directly, without creating any sidecar file.

Comment: hello @IvandalBosco, unfortunately no, it seems there's no way to prevent sidecar in the ViewNX-i software. I think I will either use a Lightroom plugin to set up the GPS coordinates or to program a small software that just do the transfer between the sidecar file to the GPS Exif metadata in the JPEG / RAWS.

Comment: Thanks a lot @puffp!